# Populate dynamic arrays with elements using AngularJS and JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, sqlite

I have a cross platform app developed using AngularJS, Monaca and Onsen UI.

I have a ***service*** that ***gets*** and ***sets*** values to be access from various ***controllers*** throughout the app.

I have various SQLite database tables created already and each one populated with values. What I need to do is access the tables and store the table values in their "corresponding" arrays in order for them to be accessible from the apps ***views***.

First, I initialise the arrays to store the values that will be retrieved from the database tables. Then I create the table-array association JSON which will match the array to be populated with its corresponding table as the small extract shows below.

```
// Init Arrays and Table association
var FruitArray = [];
var VegArray = [];

var formArrays = [{
    tablename: "tb_fruit",
    arrayname: "FruitArray"
}, {
    tablename: "tb_veg",
    arrayname: "VegArray"
}];
```

Next, I ***query*** the SQLite tables and used the retrieved values to populate the arrays as the sample below shows.

```
var myFunctions = {
    initFormData: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < formArrays.length; i++) {
            myFunctions.queryTable(formArrays[i].tablename, formArrays[i].arrayname);
        }
    },

    // Query the Tables
    queryTable: function (tableName, arrayName) {
        var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableName;

        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql(sql, [],
                (function (arrayName) {
                    return function (tx, results) {
                        myFunctions.querySuccess(tx, results, arrayName);
                    };
                })(arrayName), myFunctions.queryError);
        });
    },
```

So far s good. In my ***success callback*** below I try and push the data retrieved from the table to the array - but with no luck. I have done something similar previously but adding data to arrays in AngularJS ala. *$scope[arrayName].push(results.rows.item(i))*. But I cant seem to do the same in this case.

```
    // Success Callback
    querySuccess: function (tx, results, arrayName) {

        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            alert("Array Name: " + arrayName + // Working - returns name e.g. VegArray 
                "\n Results: " + results.rows.item(i)); // Working - returns [object Object]

            [arrayName].push(results.rows.item(i));
            alert("Array: " + [arrayName]); // Not working here - simply returns name e.g. VegArray
        }
    },

    // Error Callback
    queryError: function (tx, err) {
        alert("An error has occured);
    },
} // myFunctions() end
return myFunctions;
```

How do I push the values from my tables to the arrays? Is this the best method (guessing no) or is there a better way (guessing yes).